# Inserting button with function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is my code:

```
function ayee() {
    confirm("Ready to play?");
    var age = prompt("How old are you?"),
    replacement = document.getElementById('container'),
    message;
    if (age >= 18) {
        message = "Let's get started!" ;
    } else {
        message = "You're under 18? Be careful out there....";
    }
    replacement.innerHTML = message ;
}
```

What I want to do is in the return if age is greater then 18, add a button along with the message(or containing the message) that on click will send into the next function.

PS: this is for a choose your own adventure game.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: If i add + <button etcetc.. /> to either the message or the  replacement.innerHTML = message (here ) ; , the entire thing doesnt work on the initial button press. @Felix Kling

Comment: Aha. Please post exactly what you tried and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: @Felixkling http://jsfiddle.net/XjVcu/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't show how you tried to add the button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

attach a button, alongside your html to be displayed, and add a click handler to the button with the function you want to trigger when the button is clicked, for example a simple code can be like:

```
function ayee() {
    confirm("Ready to play?");
    var age = prompt("How old are you?"),
    replacement = document.getElementById('container'),
    message;
    if (age >= 18) {
        //create a button
        var btn = "<input type='button' name='test' onclick='checkThis();' value='Click'>"; 
        //add the button to the message
        message = "Let's get started!" + btn ;
    } else {
        message = "You're under 18? Be careful out there....";
    }
    replacement.innerHTML = message ;
}
function checkThis() {
    alert("Clicked the button");
}
```

Comment: I'd expect more from a high rep user than just posting a block of code.

Comment: Some blocks of code you just can't unsee. Why, why, why would you write something so awful?

Comment: @sirnomnomz be wary that "works perfectly" doesn't always mean "good code". The button creation is sloppy, and inline JS should be banished.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
replacement.innerHTML = message+"<button>Next</button>"
var s = replacement.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
s.addEventListener("click",function() {alert("next");}) // change the function to
                                                        // suit your needs
```

The idea is [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) creates the DOM. You can then use normal JavaScript function [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) to get the button inside your replacement

Then add an event listener on the click of the button using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

This will work only on [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Browser_compatibility). To make it work in IE prior to IE9 please add the following code. See the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility) for more details

```
if(s.addEventListener)
     s.addEventListener("click",myFunction);
else if (s.attachEvent)
     s.attachEvent("click", myFunction);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pTT5/)

Answer (score 0):

Write your function with some param

```
function myfunction(message){
//do something with message
}
```

and change `message = "Let's get started!" ;` to `myfunction('Let's get started!')`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP wants to show a button alongside the message.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.value = "Begin";

if (age >= 18) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        eighteen();
    });
}
else {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        notEighteen();
    }); 
}

container.appendChild(btn):
```

You could also call one generic function that checks the age and runs two different sections of code instead of adding event listeners for two different functions.

Just a note: when you declare a variable, you should place "var" behind it. (`var a = "test";`.)